# Retrieve multiple record values on delphi 7 with array

Tags: mysql, arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I am currently working on little project and got stuck at this matter.
So, i created a temp table which is containing item details, what i want is when i press button [save] and it will retrieve those records specific values and put the values into different temp variables.

this is what i did for selecting the specific record values.

```
DM.Zread.close;
DM.Zread.SQL.Commatext:= 'Select id_dvd from temp_table where rent_id="rent-0001"';
DM.Zread.open;
```

e.g :
selected record values :

```
id_dvd
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 5 |
```

as i said before, i wanted to put those record values into 3 different temp variables.
so it will be like :

```
//assumed i did the array function

a:=x[0]; // this line contain value from record one which is 2
b:=x[1]; // this line contain value from record two which is 6
c:=x[2]; // this line contain value from record three which is 5
```

And i totally have no idea to do this, i've searched on stackoverflow and there isn't any thread discussed about this. But i've got little reference that this methode should be using **Array** function, that's why i made the example using array. to be honest, i am not really understood using **Array**.

It will be appreciate for who help me through this.

Thank you

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know how many rows will be returned by the query you should create a dynamic array to hold the values, then after opening the table, loop over the records and fill the array:

```
var
  i: integer;
  IDs: array of integer;
begin
  DM.Zread.close;
  DM.Zread.SQL.Text:= 
      Format('Select id_dvd from temp_table where rent_id=%s',[QuotedStr('rent-0001')]);
  DM.Zread.open;

  SetLength(IDs, DM.Zread.RecordCount);
  i:=0;
  while not DM.Zread.Eof do begin
    IDs[i] := DM.Zread.FieldByName('id_dvd').AsInteger;
    inc(i);
    DM.Zread.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: really appreciate with the answer, this is what i means. this code works fine when i run it, but it give me '**Invalid Pointer Operation**' when i press the save button. i've search on stackoverflow. It says "i freed memory that didn't belong to me". What does it mean and how to make them straight ?

Comment: I made a change on this lines and it's works fine now.  `SetLength(IDs, DM.Zread.RecordCount);`   Am i doing right thing or just messed up and will make another problem future ?

Comment: @Dany2014 you did the right change, it should be `RecordCount` without the (-1)